# How to change device UDID to lowercase?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, udid

I accidentally adding my tester device UDID with uppercase and when I try to distribute my app using Fabric it said that the device is not yet added to device list on my provisioning profile.

I tried fix this with disabling my tester device with uppercase then add the new one with the same UDID but in lowercase but this only enabling the old device with the uppercase.

I already emailed apple support but no answer yet, Do any of you guys ever having the same problem? How can I fix this? My tester can test my app because of this.

Here is the alert I got from fabric:
[image]